# Selenium conditional wait with intermediate action

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying to perform an action in Selenium where it would wait till the status changes to certain “Finished” status.

Conceptually, it can be laid out in pseudo-code as this:

```
public boolean waitForActionToComplete(long maxTimeoutInSeconds, int repeatTimeInSeconds, Callable<T> action, Callable<T> condition) {
    long startTime = 0;
    while (startTime < maxTimeoutInSeconds)
        perform <action>;                   // e.g., click on a "Refresh" button to refresh the results
        boolean done = verify <condition>;  // e.g., check whether the job status is "Done"
        if (done)           
            return true;                    // if done, then exit with TRUE
        else
            Thread.sleep(repeatTimeInSeconds);
    end while;

    return false;                           // status still not complete, timeout gracefully
}
```

This method can likely be implemented in somewhat easy way with ExpectedCondition and WebdriverWait/FluentWait. However, due to certain constraints in the framework, I cannot exactly implement and use the method like so. The above method would have to be implemented as this (implements an Interface in framework having this method signature):

```
public void execute(final WebDriver webDriver, String... parameters) {
 // implementation here
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to transform the method in the form specified above?

Comment: You should investigate [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [FluentWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html).

Comment: Thanks JeffC. I appreciate it. It makes sense. I figured I did not have the problem statement complete above. I have completed it now.

Comment: You can still do what you have described with a FluentWait. You'll just have to implement it yourself with the specifics on whatever `verify <condition>` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am trying to perform an action in Selenium where it would wait till the status changes to certain “Finished” status.*

This could be achieved simply using `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated` insteadof creating own custom method `waitForActionToComplete` as  below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(byObject, "Finished"));
```

Hope it helps...:)